# Problem with is_tax in WP_Query loop

Tags: wp-query

The code below is the 2nd of 4 loops in "page-balls.php". Everything else is working correctly.

I'm trying to display a tennis ball graphic if the post being retrieved has a the term "tennis-ball" term. It's not working. Is this because the PAGE does not have the term TENNIS-BALL?

How can I make this work correctly?

```
<?php       
$args = array (
'post_type' => 'balls',
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'ASC'                
) ;

$myQuery = new WP_Query( $args ) ;
?>

<?php if ($myQuery->have_posts()) : while ($myQuery->have_posts()) : $myQuery->the_post(); ?>

<?php if(is_tax( 'ball-types', 'tennis-ball' )) : ?> 
    SHOW THE TENNIS BALL GRAPHIC
<?php else : ?>
    SHOW THE PLACEHOLDER GRAPHIC
<?php endif ; ?>

<?php endif ; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata() ; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The codex on [`is_tax`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax):

> This [Conditional Tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) checks if a custom taxonomy archive page is being displayed.

That is not the condition you want to check for.

Take a look at the [`has_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) function and use it like so:

```
if( has_term( 'tennis-ball', 'ball-types', $post->ID ) ) { 
    /* SHOW THE TENNIS BALL GRAPHIC */
} else {
    /* SHOW THE PLACEHOLDER GRAPHIC */
}
```

And as an aside, remove some of the `<?php` opening and closing tags. They serve no purpose and simply make your code less legible.

Comment: Thanks for the help Johanne. Appreciated. Re. the aside... Actually, I prefer writing my PHP this way. Once there's a lot of HTML in there, I find it much easier to read by placing the PHP in individual blocks. It's just a personal pref.

Comment: Obviously, @Wicky, you may write your code as you see fit - who am I to say what works for you personally. Should you ever have to work in cooperation with other developers though, I promise you this practice will become an issue. Also, *ideally* logic and markup don't mix. I realize that's not always possible, though. Anyhoo, if the main aspect of this answer solved your immediate problem (which I am quite confident it did), be so kind as to tick the checkmark to the left of the answer, such that others that have a similar issue can tell it is resolved.